# MvvmCross Android: Binding lost after screen rotation

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

My binding work fine, but after screen rotation I loose binding.

In OnCreateView I try to restore fragment by Tag, if FindFragmentByTag return null I create a new instance like this:

```
protected virtual TFragmentType PutFragment<TFragmentType, TViewModelType>(int oldId, TViewModelType vm)
        where TFragmentType : FragmentBase, new()
        where TViewModelType : IViewModelBase
    {
        var tag = typeof(TFragmentType).FullName;
        var fragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(tag) as TFragmentType;
        if (fragment == null)
        {
            fragment = new TFragmentType() { ViewModel = vm };
            SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(oldId, fragment, tag).Commit();
            fragment.RetainInstance = true;
        }
        return fragment;
    }
```

The probleme occur when GetFragmentByTag return some thing (in my case after sctreen rotation).

**ScreenShots**

**Before rotation:**

[image: Normal]

**After:**

[image: Empty]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See the following post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908810/mvvmcross-android-rotating-fragment-view-during-viewmodel-population

This worked for me

Comment: +1 to Sean's suggestion. Your problem here is probably **not** that the bindings are missing - but rather that the fragment has lost it's DataContext/ViewModel - so you need to give it back a new one. It may help to edit the question to include the code where you set the ViewModel for the fragment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you guys, I specified "ConfigurationChanges" in the activity attribute

```
[Activity (ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden)]
```

it work fine now

Answer (score 2):

(ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation ) is enough;